# how to do a recursion without stack overflow in python?

Tags: python, database, function, recursion, concurrency

I am working on a project with ZODB database, and have the following problem:

```
def balance(db, id, max_sleep, manager=None):
'''to calculate the funds of an account(saving + checking)'''
if manager is None:
    transaction = TransactionManager()
else:
    transaction = manager
transaction.begin()
try:
    name = db['account'][id].getName()
    funds = db['saving'][name].balance + db['checking'][name].balance
    transaction.commit()
    return funds
except Exception:
    sleep(randint(0, max_sleep)*(10**-6))
    balance(db, id, max_sleep, manager)
```

I need to recurse the function until a transaction has finished; I don't need them to be stacked, I tried adding more sleep time but the transactions still need to recurse so much(even if there are just 2 threads!). Is there a way to solve this problem!?

Comment: A while loop won't cause a stack overflow.  There is no true need to perform recursion in this instance.

Comment: Just a note about what @Mark already said; Your `balance` function is _[tail recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)_. That is to say, the very last thing that it does in one branch is to call itself. True tail recursion can always be re-factored as a loop. Some compilers for some programming languages will even [do that for you automatically](http://wiki.c2.com/?TailCallOptimization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `while` loop instead:

```
def balance(db, id, max_sleep, manager=None):
  '''to calculate the funds of an account(saving + checking)'''
  if manager is None:
      transaction = TransactionManager()
  else:
      transaction = manager
  while True:
    transaction.begin()
    try:
      name = db['account'][id].getName()
      funds = db['saving'][name].balance + db['checking'][name].balance
      transaction.commit()
      return funds
    except Exception:
      sleep(randint(0, max_sleep)*(10**-6))
```